# Vuetify Menu in header slot of data-table

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm trying to put a `<v-menu>` within the header slot of a `<v-data-table>`.

This menu would then show filter options (`v-autocomplete`) for that column.

When the menu is clicked, I can't click the autocomplete to show its items, because then the menu closes.

Is this not possible in Vuetify?

I've tried passing `:close-on-click="false"` and `:close-on-content-click="false"`

For example ([CodePen](https://codepen.io/codepen123456789/pen/poKwKLV)):

```html
<v-data-table :items="desserts" :headers="headers">
  <template #[`header.calories`]>      
    <v-menu top>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-btn icon v-bind="attrs" v-on="on"><v-icon>filter</v-icon></v-btn>
      </template>
      <v-autocomplete class="black" :items="headers" />
    </v-menu>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Event.stopPropagation()`, it will prevents further propagation of the current event

**Eg:**

```
<v-autocomplete @click="clickOnAutocomplete" class="black" :items="headers" />
...
 methods: {
    clickOnAutocomplete(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    },
  }
....
```